# when i give absolute position to the color 2(div) it while color1 is relative suddenly disappear the border-bottom

Tags: html, css

When I give absolute position to the color 2(div) it while color1 is
relative suddenly disappear the border-bottom

```css
.color1 {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted;
  display: inline-block;
}

.color2 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="color1">muthu
  <span class="color2">dinesh</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning your border-bottom a color. Otherwise different browsers will decide for you.

border-bottom: 2px **red** dotted;

Answer (score 0):

Since your .color1 is now relative and .color2 ( span element is absolute )  , your .color1 (div element) width is only taken into account ... So the width of  `.color1 + .color2  =  width of .color2 only` you need to add a border bottom to the .color2 also !

To prove my point you can make `.color1 { display : block}`
After it you can clearly see what's happening

Comment: @Dinesh.r Using max-content css  property you can easily see absolute one is basically not taken into the block  !

Comment: my question is why the color2 div bottom-border is gone why happening to it but it parent of color1(div) that's my question ,sir?

Comment: @Dinesh.r As I explained the .color1 div is parent in which .color2 can freely move .. imagine a container and ball  the ball can move inside the container so the walls of the container are considered while ball isn't of any value of boundaries ! ... If any doubt ask me !

Comment: when color1(div) is relative with bottom-border and the color2(div) is absolute ,the color1(div) didn't give bottom-border to the color2(div) why? but when the color2(div) is relative or static or none it give the bottom-border why it is happening to it that's my question.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the position of the child span to absolute, the [containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details) becomes the parent's box, which is why the border won't show on it. The simplest solution is to just set `border: inherit;` on the span:

```css
.color1 {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted;
  display: inline-block;
}

.color2 {
  position: absolute;
  border: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="color1">muthu
  <span class="color2">dinesh</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what is containing blocks?

Comment: @Dinesh.r follow the link

Comment: i didn't understand that , the containing block becomes the parent's box